# emacs function to send password to minibuffer when asked for

Tags: emacs, ssh, passwords, prompt, minibuffer

I usually connect to a machine through SSH and using `ssh.el`. I defined a command so I can do this quickly:

```
(defun ssh-me()
  (interactive)
  (ssh "myuser@myhost"))
```

After that, the mini-buffer asks me for the password and everything works fine. I am wondering if there is a way to set my password in my function so I don't have to write it every time I want to connect to that machine, so I would have something like:

```
(defun ssh-me()
  (interactive)
  (ssh "myuser@myhost")
  (send-password-to-minibuffer "mypasswd"))
```

Is that possible?

Comment: What about using ssh config or `.netrc` ? Just asking.

Comment: It really sounds like you're looking for certificate based authentication for ssh.  This doesn't answer your question directly, but I feel like this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Not familiar with ssh.el, but maybe you could solve this by creating an identify file without a passphrase to log you in without a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using a small custom file that is not encrypted.  In this example, the filename is `.authinfo_iphone` and it contains just one line -- I use it to connect to my jailbroken iphone via ssh:

```
machine localhost login root password alpine port ssh
```

Then, I use a small function to connect:

```lisp
(defun lawlist-remote-iphone-data ()
(interactive)
  (let ((auth-sources '("/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.authinfo_iphone")))
    (find-file "/ssh:root@localhost#2222:/private/var/mobile/.0.data/")))
```

---

You could also use an external utility such as `sshpass` and then write-up a function -- the command-line looks like:

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'my-password' ssh my-username@12.34.56.789
```

And here is an example function that incorporates that command line to log-in to the iPhone over ssh.  It contemplates there is already an open shell-mode buffer with the process named `*shell*`.

```lisp
(defun shell-iphone ()
"From an existing shell buffer with a process named `*shell*`,
log-in to the iPhone using sshpass."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      (password "alpine")
      (port "2222")
      (username "root")
      (host "localhost")
      (sshpass "/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/bin/sshpass")
      (ssh "/usr/bin/ssh")
      (dir "/private/var/mobile/.0.data"))
    (comint-send-string "*shell*"
      (mapconcat 'identity `(
        ,sshpass
        "-p"
        ,password
        ,ssh
        "-p"
        ,port
        "-l"
        ,username
        ,host
        "-t"
        "\"cd " ,dir " && bash --login\"") " "))
    (comint-send-input)))
```

Comment: I ended up using a bit different solution, but I'm using `sshpass` and modified the emacs function. Thanks for your help :)